# Discrepancy in pandas version shown in python and anaconda

Tags: pandas, anaconda, zipline

I am testing out Quantopian's zipline in a python 3.5.6 environment that I created with Anaconda. Per their documentation, pandas 0.22 is the recommended version, and for my own sanity, I'd like to stay with that version.

In conda, if I do

`conda list | grep pandas`

I get the following, as expected.

```
pandas                    0.22.0           py35h0a44026_0
pandas-datareader         0.8.1                      py_0
```

However, when I am in python, I get

```
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:30:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print (pd.__version__)
0.25.3
```

Why is it doing that?  And how do I make sure that only pandas 0.22 is loaded into my python session?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you have a look at your Path? You might have different Python versions installed. You can also try updating Anaconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/

Comment: How did you launch python?

Comment: I do have two versions of python. Python 2.7 in /usr/bin/python and python 3.5.6 in /opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline35/bin/python.  I invoke python by issuing "python" at the command line and it shows that I indeed invoked the 3.5.6 as intended.  

I'm a little hesitant to update conda, I just don't know what else might break if I did so.